# best what to search a work sheet.. EXCEL VBA USER FORM

Tags: vba, excel, userform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find cell location based on value then do something- User Forms VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337413/find-cell-location-based-on-value-then-do-something-user-forms-vba-excel)

I am build a user Form and trying to figure how to write a block of code that:

*gets the value of a combo box from user.
*search for this value on a particular sheet, in a particular column
* get the cell location for this value
*returns one office set row for address, next offset row for city"

I asked this same question before, however, after sometime the answer couldnt help.

here is my code that i came up with:

```
For Each cLoc In ORISheetList.Range("ORI_LIST")
'compare the input string from list- considering using Match function for this
If StrComp(cLoc, ORIValue,  vbTextCompare) Then TextBAgencyName.Value = "test"
Else: Next cLoc
End If
```

the for Each loop and if conditionals dont really work well together.

i've read there is a find function on vba excel. is there a way to utlize that to get the location of the cell? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Set cLoc = ORISheetList.Range("ORI_LIST").find ORIValue
If not cLoc is nothing then
    ' you found it!
```